# How do I set the date of a Calendar control from the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a calendar selection which needs to be populated on page load from a column stored in database.

**Example:**

```
Id = 71
String D1= "select date from customer where ID= 71";
Calendar1=???
```

I have date stored in D1 in string format and Calendar1 is the ID of the calendar. I tried searching google but couldn't find the syntax for assigning that date to calendar1 on page load.

Could you help me in date conversion syntax and assigning it Calendar.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can simply set the [`SelectedDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selecteddate%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) property of the [`Calendar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar_properties%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) control:

```
Calendar1.SelectedDate = ...;
```

however, you're going to need to go get that date. You have a `SELECT` statement there so do something like this:

```
using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection("your connection string"))
{
    c.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select date from customer where ID = @ID", c))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Id);
        var val = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        Calendar1.SelectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(val);
    }
}
```